# How to plot a thermodynamic cycle?

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise, chemistry

I try to plot a thermodynamic cycle with the data displayed using the tool, "Piecewise", but in the case of isochoric and isobaric processes, Mathematica shows nothing. Could someone please tell me how to fix this?

```
n=10;R=8.3145;Ta=1497;Tb=Tc=1152;Td=299;Va=Vd=0.249;Vb=0.479;Vc=0.958;pa=500000;pb=200000;pc=pd=100000;\[Gamma]=1.4;

(*Adiabatic*)
pAB[V_] := pa*(Va/V)^\[Gamma];
(*Isothermal*)
pBC[V_] := n*R*Tc/V;
(*Isobaric*)
pCD[V_] := n*R*Td/Vd;
(*Isochoric*)
pDA[V_] := n*R*Ta/V;

Plot[Piecewise[{{pAB[V],Va<=V<=Vb},{pBC[V],Vb<=V<=Vc},{pCD[V],Vc<=V<=Vd},{pDA[V],V==Va}}],{V,0.2,1.0},ImageSize -> Large]
```

Thanks.

Comment: For the isobaric process, your inequality is `Vc <= V <= Vd` but `Vc = 0.958` and `Vd = 0.249`. No matter what value `V` has, this inequality must always be false and is therefore never evaluated. For the isochoric process, you just have `V == Va`, so this will only plot at one infinitesimal point on the x axis. It has no width, so I'm not sure whether Mathematica simply ignores it, or perhaps it is actually plotted on the graph – without any width, it's impossible to say.

Comment: I should add that if you're trying to plot a thermodynamic cycle, `Plot` is only for plotting functions. If it fails the vertical line test, it's not going to work properly with `Plot`. One possibility is to break it into 4 separate functions (rather than combining into a single Piecewise), so long as all of them are functions and not relations. You may also want to check out `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Piecewise is very suitable for this tasks. Prefer: `Plot[{Piecewise[{{pAB[V], Va <= V <= Vb}}], 
  Piecewise[{{pBC[V], Vb <= V <= Vc}}], 
  Piecewise[{{pCD[V], Vc <= V <= Vd}}], 
  Piecewise[{{pDA[V], V == Va}}]}, {V, 0.2, 1.0}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]`. It seems that the value of `n` is much too small.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Carnot cycle diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191753/carnot-cycle-diagram)

Comment: @user2432923: Your proposed solution doesn't plot the $C \to D$ or $D \to A$ legs correctly, for the reasons described by MassDefect.  Judging from the description, the $C \to D$ line should be a horizontal line at $P = 100000$;  the $D \to A$ leg should be a vertical line at $V = 0.249$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One could in principle use `RegionPlot` to do this, though it requires some finesse:

```
RegionPlot[(p < pAB[v] || p < pBC[v]) && p > pCD[v] && v > Va, {v, 0, 
  1}, {p, 0, 500000}, PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Note that I had to be a bit clever with the combination of the logical conditions.  The naive choice of conjoining all of them with `&&` doesn't work in this case, since the $A \to B$ adiabat continues below the $B\to C$ isotherm.